# Why is preventDefault() not working in ReactJS properly?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I have a "Join" button:

```
const sendMessage = (e) => {
        if (message) {
            socket.emit('send', message, ()=>{setMessage('')});
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input value={message}
                onChange={(e)=>{
                    setMessage(e.target.value);}}
                onKeyPress={(e)=>{return e.key==='Enter' ? sendMessage(e) : console.log('no good');}}
                 />
        </div>
    )
```

After filling out the input field and pressing Enter, my socket-io id changes due to page refreshing. To prevent  refresh, I used `e.preventDefault()` in `sendMessage` function, but despite it, the page refreshes anyway and the socket-io id changes. How to prevent page-refresh?

Answer (score 1):

Your `input` will only cause a refresh if it's within a `form` which your example is not. If you need to prevent a refresh from the form you can do it within `onSubmit` like the following example.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
    
export default function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  function sendMessage(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          value={message}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setMessage(e.target.value);
          }}
          onKeyPress={(e) => {
            return e.key === "Enter" ? sendMessage(e) : console.log("no good");
          }}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I did it as you have shown above but the socket-io id is again changing.

Comment: You will need to maintain the socket in a stable reference, like a ref or context provider.

Comment: Ok, I was trying to do it like here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwFA3YMfkoc at 1:14:40. He only writes `e.preventDefault()`, it works out for him, though not for me.